# Submit a Form with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Trying to get my register page posting the data to the database using Ajax and jQuery but having great difficulty.

I'm very new to ajax and cane seem to get my head around how to do this insert.
Would be very grateful of any advice regarding how to do this. Im not sure if what i have got is even remotely close at the moment.

As current when I click the submit button the page refreshes but there is no change to the database.

*html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/registerpost.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="mainContent")>
    <form class="basic-grey"  method="post">
      <h1>Registration Form<span>Please complete all fields.</span></h1>
      <p>
        <label><span>First Name:</span>
          <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Surname:</span>
          <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" placeholder="Surname" required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Username:</span>
          <input name="username" id="username" oninput="checkUsername();" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" placeholder="Username" required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Email:</span>
          <input name="email" id="email" oninput="checkEmail();" type="email" size="40" maxlength="40" placeholder="Email" required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Password:</span>
          <input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" size="40" maxlength="40" placeholder="********" required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Confirm Password:</span>
          <input name="password2" id="password2" oninput="checkPassword();" type="password" size="40" placeholder="********" required/>
        </label>
      </p>
      <div align="center"><span align = "center" id="user-result"></span><br><br><br>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

php code

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';

    $hash = password_hash($_POST['password2'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 11]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members(firstname, lastname, username, email, password )
                      VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password )";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $results->$stmt->execute();

        if($results) {
            echo 'Welcome new member, and thanks you for registering with the website.';
            echo '<br><br>Click <a href="../index.html">here</a> to return to the login page';
        } else {
            echo 'Did not work.';
        }
    ?>
```

js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit_btn').click(function(){

            var data = {};
            data.firstname = $('#firstname').val();
            data.lastname = $('#lastname').val();
            data.username = $('#username').val();
            data.email = $('#email').val();
            data.password2 = $('#password2').val();


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../php/newuser.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });
                return false;
        });

    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do a print_r($db->errorInfo()); see if any error

Comment: Also (minor point I noticed will looking through the code), remove the double closing form tag </form>.  It won't solve the problem, but should be done.

Comment: It's a matter of finding out how far you ARE getting, then we can help. Here's some guidance: do an `alert()` inside your click function to make sure it's working. Do a `console.log(data)` before your ajax to ensure all the values are present. do a `var_dump($_POST)` on the PHP side to verify the form was received.

Comment: The page shouldn't reload since you return `false` from the click handler. Check your JS console to see if there are errors preventing the code from running.

Comment: I'd also change your #submit_btn.click to:  $('#form_id').submit(function(event){ event.stopPropagation();  And give your form an ID of #form_id (example).

Comment: I have just done a successful alert and console.log all of the values have been passes successfully. Does this mean that my error will be in the php file? Thanks people

Answer (score 1):

Solved it was a simple error that i had made in the PHP file.

This

```
$results->$stmt->execute();
```

To this

```
$results = $stmt->execute();
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. See details here: 
https://webdevideas.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/n-forms-one-javascript/

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ajaxform").bind("submit",function(e){

```
e.preventDefault();

var ajaxurl = $(this).attr("action");

var data = $(this).serialize();

$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(res){

    $("#message").html(res.message);

},'json');
```

});

});